# Azure DevOps: What's the difference between the "Hosted Linux Preview" and "Hosted Ubuntu 1604" agent pools?

Tags: linux, docker, azure-devops

I have some build pipelines that build Linux based Docker images and run on the Hosted Linux Preview pool.  Recently I noticed a pool called Hosted Ubuntu 1604.  On [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted), Hosted Linux Preview is not mentioned, and Ubuntu 1604 is recommended for Docker.

So is Hosted Linux Preview deprecated or are there still reasons to use it?  Should I be migrating my pipelines to Hosted Ubuntu 1604?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Microsoft-hosted agents page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=vsts&tabs=yaml#hosted-linux-preview-pool-deprecation) now has information on the deprecation of the Hosted Linux Preview pool and how to migrate over to the Hosted Ubuntu 1604 pool.  (I'm sure this information wasn't there when I asked this question, but I could be wrong...).